# javafx iText, как отобразить содержимое пдф файла в модальном окне?

Tags: javafx, pdf, itext

Не могу понять как это должно работать, нашел на форуме такой код:

```
@FXML
void preview (ActionEvent event) {

    try {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("SecondWindow.fxml"));
    Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
    Stage modalWindow = new Stage();
    modalWindow.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    modalWindow.setTitle("Предпросмотр");
    modalWindow.setScene(new Scene(root1));
    modalWindow.showAndWait();

    String FILE = "D:\\День рождения, Михаил Мархель.pdf";

    Document document = new Document();

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(FILE);

        document.open();

        int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(FILE));


        PdfImportedPage page;
        page = writer.getImportedPage(reader,n);
        Image instance = Image.getInstance(page);

        writer.close();
        document.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как полученное изображение разместить в новом окне?

Answer (score 0):

```
SecondWindowController.class.cast(fxmlLoader.getController()).placingImageFromParentWindow(instance);
((SecondWindowController) fxmlLoader.getController()).placingImageFromParentWindow(instance);
```

Замените SecondWindowController на тот, что используется у вас в `SecondWindow.fxml` и создайте в нем метод `placingImageFromParentWindow`.

После вызова `fxmlLoader.load` из лоадера можно получить нужный экземпляр используемого на втором окне контроллера в который уже прокинуть все необходимое.